# android: My application is not able to access the internet on Emulator

Tags: android

I developed android application which is working fine on real device and can access the internet but when i am running it on emulator is not working(not able to access internet).

I can access internet on emulator, i checked that with the internet browser (able to open few web pages from emulator's browser) but my application is not able to use it.

Can anyone please help me why this problem is coming ?

Thank you.

Comment: any Logcat Error? what is the OS of device and what is the OS of emulator?

Comment: Is the site your app is trying to access accessible through the browser? Perhaps you're behind a proxy that blocks it.

Answer (score 0):

hi even i too faced this similar issue.. i tried the following things and it worked fine

```
  1)close your emulator
  2)Kill the adb process
  3)start the adb
  4) restart your eclispse than run it again..
```

I hope it may work.... for me it worked....

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 things:

```
     - Recheck your manifest file that it has internet permission or not
```

```
    - Do this on your eclipse Run->Run config->select your app then go to Target->put -dns-server 8.8.8.8 in Additional commandline option for your emulator and run;
```

Hope this helps :) cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from command line . `emulator -avd Machine2.3 -no-boot-anim -dns-server 8.8.8.8`